# Alternative solutions to missing shared libraries after cross compilation?

Tags: rust, cross-compiling, rust-cargo

I first cross compile my Rust project to linux target

```
cargo build --target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Then run `ldd` on my local ubuntu and the linker works fine.

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffddc62000)
libssl.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f6d34500000)
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f6d340b0000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f6d33ea0000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f6d33c90000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f6d33a70000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f6d33850000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6d33440000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6d35a00000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f6d330a0000)
```

But on my target os, `ldd` fails to find the libraries

```
libssl.so.1.0.0 => not found
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => not found
/lib64/libc.so.6 => version `GLIBC_2.18' not found
```

Actually I have `libssl.so.10` and `libcrypto.so.10` installed under `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Unfortunately I am not able to install shared libraries of version `1.0.0` required by Rust.

I have read [Rust Cross](https://github.com/japaric/rust-cross) and the recommended solution is to install the missing shared libraries. Unfortunately that's not possible for me. So I am looking for alternative solutions to missing libraries.

`libssl.so.1.0.0` and `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` sound ancient. How can I tell `cargo` to use a later version?

How can I deal with `/lib64/libc.so.6 => version GLIBC_2.18 not found`?

Comment: Actually, the `lib{ssl,crypto}.so.6` are quite older than the `*.so.1.0.0` counterparts. My guess is that your compiler system is much more modern than the target system. If you cannot upgrade the target maybe you can downgrade the cross-compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3643072), `GLIBC_2.18` can't be installed to `RHEL7`. I gave up dynamically linked libraries.

This [post](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl/issues/980) helped me out. The solution is:

```
[dependencies]
nats = "*"
protobuf = { version = "~2.0" }
# Add openssl-sys as a direct dependency so it can be cross compiled to
# x86_64-unknown-linux-musl using the "vendored" feature below
openssl-sys = "*"

[features]
# Force openssl-sys to staticly link in the openssl library. Necessary when
# cross compiling to x86_64-unknown-linux-musl.
vendored = ["openssl-sys/vendored"]
```

This way I can compile to a single executable with no library dependencies using:

```
cargo build --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-musl --features vendored
```